# Reading data from XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml

I dont know how to read data from such XML file. Lets say i want to read every every GUID and userID. How do i do it?

Here is part of XML: http://pastebin.com/7B25eyFz

Comment: A quick google search with your question title would have ended up in all the solutions that people have answered here. Follow this article to see how you can search on google efficiently.http://www.dumblittleman.com/2007/06/20-tips-for-more-efficient-google.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your xml file is Tree base then use DOM, if it is not nested then use SAX, is faster then DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into [SAX Parser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html).  Also, do a search for your terms - there are a ton of questions about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [trail about XML](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) of the Java tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an XML library like [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/).  You can then use it to query the XML document using XPATH.  XOM offers a [tutorial](http://www.xom.nu/tutorial.xhtml).

Comment: The javax.xml.xpath APIs in Java can also be used for performing XPath queries.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to `@user651407` point, If you just want to read the XML then go for `SAX`, It parses the `XML` in serial fashion so its faster, but if you want to do more complex operation like Adding, Updating or deleting a node then go for `DOM` but `DOM` Has Limitation
`1. required more memory as entire XML is loaded at a time.`
`2. Slow in processing as it is a tree based parser.`